# Entity Framework select many-to-many with concat text

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application

[image: diag]

clases

Book: Id, Name, Content, Publishment
Author: Id,Name
is many-to-many

Book

```
Id   |   Name   |   Content   |   Publishment
1        book1    somecontent     some pub
2        book2     somecont        somepub
```

Author

```
Id   |   Name
1        Author1
2        Author2
3        Author3
4        Author4
```

BookAuthor

```
IdBook   |   IdAuthor
1            2
1            3
1            4
2            1
2            3
```

How can I get something like:

```
Name   |   Content   |   Author
Book1    some content     Author2,Author3,Author3
Book2     somecontent      Author1,Author3
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

I assume based on looking at this you're using DB-first.  If that's the case, your entities are created as partial classes.  Create a new partial class file for your Book class and add a new property to retrieve the author names.  Something like this:

```
public partial class Book
{
   public string AuthorNames => string.Join(", ", authors.Select(a => a.Name));
}
```

To prevent multiple trips to the database to retrieve the associated authors, use include when retrieving your books.

```
var books = myContext.Books.Include(nameof(Book.authors));
```

Another way is to use projection to create an anonymous type.

```
var books = myContext.Books
   .Select(b => new { 
      b.Name, 
      b.Content, 
      AuthorNames = b.authors.Select(a => a.Name) 
   })
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(b => new {
      b.Name,
      b.Content,
      Authors = string.Join(", ", b.AuthorNames)
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i have a proublem: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.   If i use authors = string.Join(", ", b.authors.Select(a => a.Name)) i have message: 
The LINQ to Entities expression does not recognize the method"System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])"so it can not be converted to a storage expression. ' What can i do ?

Comment: Ah, that's because Linq can't translate string.Join() to SQL to execute against the database.  You have to query the db into memory (you can do that by calling ToList()) before using that expression.  I've attempted to correct the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the string of corrections, it's been a long day.

Comment: The `Include` in the second query is redundant: the projection eliminates it. A possible optimization is to use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`.

Comment: Yep, great points.  I wasn't even aware of AsEnumerable() as an option for this.  Edited to incorporate your recommendations.  Thanks!